# Apache Directory Studio error when importing LDIF with request control attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap, apacheds

I'm trying to import a LDIF that contains a request control attribute using Apache Directory Studio but I'm getting a null error. There's no more information than the null error.
The LDAP Server I'm running is NOT ApacheDS.

The same LDIF works fine when importing using the ldapmodify command line.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Does Apache Directory Studio not support request control attributes?

Following the sample LDIF:

```
dn: uid=sample,ou=SUBSCRIBER,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-NTDB
control: 1.3.6.1.4.1.30221.2.5.44
changetype: add
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: sample
givenName: sample
cn: sample
sn: sample
```

Error log:

```
version: 1

#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://X.X.X.X:636
#!DATE 2023-06-19T12:01:00.790
#!ERROR null
dn: uid=sample,ou=SUBSCRIBER,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-NTDB
control: 1.3.6.1.4.1.30221.2.5.44
changetype: add
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: sample
givenName: sample
cn: sample
sn: sample
```

Comment: What request control?

Comment: @user207421 1.3.6.1.4.1.30221.2.5.44 Name with entryUUID Request Control